# jquery issues with html height:100%

Tags: jquery, css

I have this function that fires a click when the user is 500px from the bottom of the window.

It all works fine, except when I set my html and body to height:100% in the css.

Here's the 'working' script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout = '';
    $(window).scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 500; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //if less than intBottomMargin px from bottom 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); 
          }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

How do I make the same script work when my html and body are 100% height?

I'm sure it's really simple to do.

Comment: haven't explained what isn't working...create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Also...if body height is 100% need to monitor scroll on something other than window

Comment: @charlietfl Here is a jsfiddle for you, good sir! http://jsfiddle.net/LnmsR/ remove height:100% from html and see it work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation is incorrect:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin)
```

If your body/html is 100% height, it means that you're setting it to be the height of the viewport. Did you have floated elements before? That may be why your (previous) height calculation was working

Try this instead:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - intBottomMargin)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

The thing is, my original calculation works fine when the html element has no assigned height, but it doesn't work when it's set to height:100%.
The reason body and html are both height:100% is so I can have a sidebar that can be scrolled up and down independently from the main content.

Comment: it's likely because your layout is causing $(document).height() to not reflect the height of your page. Do you have floated elements? You could try adding a clearfix (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to a container element, ie. <body class="clearfix"> to clear any floated elements, and get the true height of the page.

Comment: There's no floated elements inside the body, the container inside that is .main-content, which isn't floated.

I've making a jsfiddle of the problem just now for you guys, I appreciate the help!

Comment: here's the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LnmsR/  take away 'height:100%' then run it again, scroll to the bottom and the script fires fine.
I need it to fire when the html's height is 100%;

Comment: That works, but html needs to have overflow:auto to stop scrolling inside my sidebar scrolling the main-content!

Comment: If you keep it on, then $(window).scrollTop() will always be zero -- it's never scrolling, you're just scrolling inside the html element. You'll have to change your layout, or find another way to get the scrolled offset. Maybe look at binding .scroll() to one of your container elements

Answer (score -1):

What you are scrolling is not the `window` since `body` and `html` are set to same size as window, so window has no overflow to need a scollbar for

Scrollbar is part of body since it has overflow content. Bind scoll handler to body and it works

```
 var $scollEl=$('body').scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 500; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //if less than intBottomMargin px from bottom 

        if ($scollEl.scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $scollEl.height() - intBottomMargin) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(".clicked").click(); 
          }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/LnmsR/2/

Comment: uh, spoke too soon, now it's firing off the function multiple times.

Comment: it seems to fire off after I scroll even one pixel, then keep firing.

Comment: Yeah, but I only want it to fire once, when I'm 500px from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: clcik only happens at bottom...what browser are you using? SHould change your code so if click already happened not to do any size checks, or unbind scroll handler. scrol code can be resource intensive if constatntly searching DOM due to it firing many times a s econd

Comment: @charleitfl In chrome + safari the click happens as soon as you scroll even one pixel, works ok in firefox though.

Comment: ok..i only did it in firefox. Not sure why you just don't use window. Might have to play around with which dimensions need to be used in comparison. I did it very quick and was working in browser i was using. For example store height of main child of body and use that dimension. The more you can cache in variable that doesn't change the better due to number of times it fres

Comment: I can't work out why webkit browsers are being funny either :/

Comment: try console logging the dimensions. something not acting the same cross browser

Comment: body stays the same height in chrome as html.

Comment: Uh, I am so  stumped, why oh why doesn't webkit play nice with this.